# How to trigger(Click) Anchor tag from Pageload in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have Anchor tag (a). I want to click or trigger this Anchor tag from Pageload.
I don't want to click or trigger anchor tag from browser. Please give me any suggestions.

```
   <a href="#" class="control" id="control" runat="server">Post</a>
```

I have tried Like this,

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "Call();", true);
        }

       function Call()
       {
        document.getElementById("control").click();
        }
```

Thanks..

Comment: Explain in better mode "I don't want to click or trigger anchor tag from browser", what's your scenario?

Comment: You cannot click or trigger "from Page_Load", e.g., from CodeBehind. CodeBehind is processed, then the page is delivered to the browser. Please elaborate.

Comment: When we click on Anchor tag, That is redirect or call any function. In the same way i want to call Anchor tag from pageload

Comment: If you want to redirect server side, do it directly in the `PageLoad`, which is server side.